# AngularJs - Need help to Hook controller to the View

Tags: angularjs

I am expecting the below code to print the numbers.I tried but I am not sure what I am missing here. I am new to AngularJs

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="">

<head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-controller="MyController">
        <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="number in Numbers">{{ number }}</li>
        </ul>
</div>
   <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function MyController($scope) {

            $scope.Numbers = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']; 
        }
    </script>


    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: as has been mentioned, using angular 1.2 or greater, you can no longer declare global controller objects.  you must have a module (i.e. no empty `ng-app`), and the controller must be declared in that module.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

From Angular 1.2 onwards, you can't declare your controller globally the way you are doing right now  . You have to declare it with the module.

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    app.controller('MyController',function($scope){
      $scope.Numbers = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']; 
    })
```

See the working changes: http://plnkr.co/edit/Rp87qEQ5albeCQPYVh48?p=preview

If you insist on doing the way you are doing right now, [you can actually allow globals in your config](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$controllerProvider). Try to run the snippets below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script data-require="angularjs_1_3_15@*" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="number in Numbers">{{ number }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    function MyController($scope) {

      $scope.Numbers = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five'];
    }

    angular.module('myApp').config(['$controllerProvider',
      function($controllerProvider) {
        $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
      }
    ]);
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I am still confused a bit. I believe I am importing Angular correctly. I tried some simple scripts and they run just fine for me. I tried to explore the Chrome Developers tool to see if it complains. It complained with the following error

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=MyController&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20undefined

Comment: What version of Angular do you have?

Comment: I am using  AngularJS v1.3.16

Answer (score 0):

this completely should work. check console (F12,  developer tools) to see if you have any error message, especially if your angular.min.js is included correctly.

The following little js fiddle show you the little piece of code does work, as long as your angular js is included correctly.

```
  function MyController($scope) {

        $scope.Numbers = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']; 
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dshun/o1yg3kvp/